# How do I ignore parts of the URL?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, url

Currently I have a local server running with my main page at localhost

I ideally want the setup where the url has a key that I send off to my database to get data and the main page loads that data

For example, someone enters the url of localhost/4962 then 4962 gets sent off to the database, while localhost loads. I am using angularJS so I do have a way of getting the url by doing...

```
var module = angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
});
```

Then location.absUrl() gets me the complete URL.

But obviously there is no page at localhost/4962, so i just get a 404.
How do i ignore the numbers in the url? Also how do I get just the numbers, I would be willing to do localhost/#/4962 if a hash would simplify matters.

EDIT:
Below are some useful answers. Here is what I went with -

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/:message',
      {
        template: " ",
        controller: "AppCtrl"
      }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.model = {
        message: $routeParams.message
    }
    //debugging
    console.log($scope.model.message)
});
```

I needed to have

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

in the index.html.
[Angularjs using $routeProvider without ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335338/angularjs-using-routeprovider-without-ng-view) has a way of avoiding the addition of ng-view. Will try that next.

Comment: Why don't you parse the localhost/4962 ? you should be able to `split` the whole url using the `/` separator. Use the split method. Then pick the part you want to use.

Comment: I still have the issue where I get a 404, unless I wanted to do something like http://localhost/#/4962 with a hash, but I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/:number?', {
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/home.html'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}).run(function(){
    ...
});
```

In this case, `number` is optional route paramerer (because it has `?` at the end). Then you can get number from controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('homeCtrl', function($routeParams){

    var number = $routeParams.number;

});
```

Don't forget to include `angular-route.js` file ;)

Comment: That seems like exactly what I want, where do i put that?

Comment: It seems that http://localhost/4962 still gives a 404, 'The requested URL /4962 was not found on this server', no errors in the console.

Comment: @DustinClark seems you have some errors in your code. if you reproduce your code on jsfiddle for example, i'll be able to help

Comment: I cant seem to get even a simple barebones example to work in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KbkCT/

Comment: @DustinClark i fixed your fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KbkCT/3/  try it locally because it's impossible to navigate through routes on jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still getting nowhere, Ive tried replicating the jsfiddle code on my machine in every way and no method seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$location.path()`-Function, should return just the path (without hashtag).