# AngularJS - routing with parameter to same page as without parameter

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an static index.php page that gets loaded when you enter the base url `/`. This uses the `MainController`. I want the `MainController` to also accept a parameter from the url.

So when I enter `/someParameter`, the `someParameter` value should be accessable in the `MainController.` But the page should still load the basic index.php file.

I use `ngRoute`, but that seem to require templates that I don't have/use. Is there anyway I can do this without resorting to templates or something?

I can't seem to get `ngRoute` work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't need routing, you just want access to the query string.

You can just use `$location` to get the parameter from the query string. The answer to the question below gives an example.

[Angularjs using $routeProvider without ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335338/angularjs-using-routeprovider-without-ng-view)

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking for. Thank you. I tried searching but I had no idea what to look for.